# Excel-VBA Sort doesn't work

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have a problem with a sort function. It doesn't work. If I record a macro while sorting manually, the recorded looks like mine. The Sub looks as follows:

```
Public Sub sortSelectionByDate(ByRef wrksheet As Worksheet, ByVal fromRow As Integer, ByVal toRow As Integer)
    'debug
    toRow = toRow - 1
    wrksheet.Select
    wrksheet.Rows(fromRow & ":" & toRow).Select
    With Selection
        .Sort Key1:=Range("A9"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance....

Christoph

Comment: You sure the selection contain Range("A9") in it?

Comment: Also write custom fromRow and toRow and in sorting give its header like wrksheet.Rows("A1:D60").Select
With Selection
    .Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End With

Comment: Hi Emaad, I know it's confusing; But the Selection is correct. Starting Row is always 9. An the Sorting Column is always A.

Comment: Just write it in customize way, also allow your excel file to be editable.

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: I do a lot of formatting, which works... I also get data via a com-interface to the sheet. Basicly, what it does in that sub is, it selects the right spot of the worksheet, but id does not sort!

Comment: Formatting? It doesn't look like it should be formatting anything? How do you mean?

Comment: Chris, I called it with `code`Call sortSelectionByDate(Sheets(1), 10, 14)`code` and it ran fine in xl2010 for me. Are your ID's numeric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely not working because you're passing a worksheet that isn't the active worksheet, not activating it, then trying to sort.  Here's a link to a description of the problem you're having: [Beginning VBA: Select and Activate](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/27/beginning-vba-select-and-activate/).  Long story short, never ever use .Select or .Selection unless you want your user to be able to run code on the selection of his choice.  Even then, still not always a great idea.  Here's your sub re-written in one line:

```
Public Sub sortSelectionByDate(ByRef wrksheet As Worksheet, ByVal fromRow As Integer, ByVal toRow As Integer)
    wrksheet.Rows(fromRow & ":" & toRow - 1).Sort Key1:=wrkSheet.Range("A9"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

The important changes are:

- No need to use .Select.  If you did want to use it you'd need to use wrkSheet.Activate first.
- Change Key1:=Range("A9") to Key1:=wrkSheet.Range("A9"). Always helps to be explicit when working with cells/ranges.
- The With statement isn't needed since you're only running one method.